# How to get dates at the bottom of the tableau Graph

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a side by side bar in Tableau By using Measure names and measure values. I am using multiple measures to plot in the side by side bars. However the date axis are coming at the top . I want them at the bottom. Please see picture below:

[image]

How do I get the dates to the bottom?

Comment: I think this has been discussed before on some other thread on SO and is presently not possible in Tableau's current version

Comment: Actually it is possible in two ways

Comment: In that case please add that as answer for reference of other users